# Make dynamically created divs scroll horizontally

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a set of divs I create using javascript to continue being made horizontally. I cannot seem to figure out a solution for this. I basically need it to keep being added horizontally and then being able to scroll horizontally. At the moment they get created to edge of the browser window and then below.

```js
function makeResponseBox() {
    document.getElementById("calculate").onclick = function()
    {
        var responseBox = document.createElement("DIV"); //create <div>
        responseBox.setAttribute("class", "content" );
        document.getElementById('container').appendChild(responseBox);
    }

}//close function (makeResponseBox)

window.onload=makeResponseBox;
```

```css
body {
 margin: 0 0;
}
#container {
 border: 1px solid blue;

}
#headerbar {
 font-size: 26px;
 color: white;
 padding-left: 10px;
 border: 1px solid blue;
 height: 50px;

}
#sidebar {
 color: black;
 border: 1px solid blue;
 width: 50px;
 float: left;
 height: 100vh;
}
.content {
 width: 200px;
 height: 100vh;
 float: left;
 display: inline;
 border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

```html
<div id='container'>
<div id='headerbar'>Test Div</div>
<div id='sidebar'> <input type="button" value="Calculate" id="calculate" />
<br /><br />
<br /><br />
</div>
<div class='content'>test1</div>


</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `white-space: nowrap` on the `.container` to prevent inline items from wrapping. Set `.content` and `.sidebar` to `display: inline-block; vertical-align: top;`, and remove the float to maintain a single line:

```js
function makeResponseBox() {
    document.getElementById("calculate").onclick = function() {
      var responseBox = document.createElement("DIV"); //create <div>
      responseBox.setAttribute("class", "content");
      document.getElementById('container').appendChild(responseBox);
    }

  } //close function (makeResponseBox)

window.onload = makeResponseBox;
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0 0;
}
#container {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  white-space: nowrap; /*** prevent the divs from wrapping to the next lines ***/
  overflow: auto; /** resize the container with the added content **/
    font-size: 0; /** remove spaces between inline-block elements **/
}

#container > * {
  font-size: 16px; /** set font-size to all direct children of #container **/
}

#headerbar {
  font-size: 26px;
  color: white;
  padding-left: 10px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  height: 50px;
}
#sidebar {
  display: inline-block;
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  width: 50px;
  height: 100vh;
  vertical-align: top;
}
.content {
  display: inline-block; /*** this will make the divs stay on the same line, but still have the attributes of a block element ***/
  width: 200px;
  height: 100vh;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  margin: 0 5px 0 0;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="headerbar">Test Div</div>
  <div id="sidebar">
    <input type="button" value="Calculate" id="calculate" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
    <br />
  </div>
  <div class="content">test1</div>


</div>
```